# How do i deserialize facebook data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I Have retrieved data of Facebook groups.

```
    {
  "groups": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Name_1",
        "unread": 25,
        "bookmark_order": 13,
        "id": "000000000001"
      },   {
        "name": "Name_2",
        "unread": 25,
        "bookmark_order": 999999999,
        "id": "00000000002"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "next": "Value_URL"
    }
  },
  "id": "123456"
}
```

My attempt:

```
Public Class groups

    Public Property data() As List(Of Facebookgroups)
        Get
            Return m_data
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Facebookgroups))
            m_data = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_data As List(Of Facebookgroups)
End Class

Public Class Facebookgroups

    Public Property id() As String
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_id As String
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return m_name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_name As String
End Class
            Dim g = FBclient1.Get("me?fields=groups")

            Dim facebookgroups As groups = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of groups)(g)
            For Each item As Object In facebookgroups.data
                Console.WriteLine("id: {0}, name: {1}", item.id, item.name)
            Next
```

I am getting errors. It says not able to convert into string.
Is this the correct way to do ?
is there any other workaround for deserializing objects ?

Comment: what do you get from the FBclient.Get("me?fields=groups") call? The string you wrote above?

Comment: Yes. I get the above JSON string

Answer (score 0):

The output JSON string you wrote above returns a structure different from your class. Your class should be something along the lines of:

Class Group, that has properties data and id, the data class should have a List of the class containing properties: name, unread, bookmark_order, id.

**EDIT:**

```
Public Class Data
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property unread As Integer
    Public Property bookmark_order As Integer
    Public Property id As Integer
End Class

Public Class Paging
    Public Property next As String
End Class

Public Class Groups
    Public Property data As List(Of Data)
    Public Property paging As Paging
End Class

Public Class ResponseObject
    Public Property groups As Groups
    Public Property id As Integer
End Class
```

Parsing it as a ResponseObject should work, but I haven't tested myself.

**EDIT 2: Working example**

The below code works for me, I am reading your data from a file c:\dev\tt.json, and the groups are properly parsed if I step through.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim g = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("c:\dev\tt.json")
    Dim facebookgroups As ResponseObject = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of      ResponseObject)(g)
End Sub

Public Class Data
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property unread As Integer
    Public Property bookmark_order As Integer
    Public Property id As Integer
End Class

Public Class Paging
    Public Property [next] As String
End Class

Public Class Groups
    Public Property data As List(Of Data)
    Public Property paging As Paging
End Class

Public Class ResponseObject
    Public Property groups As Groups
    Public Property id As Integer
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I used json2csharp.com to get classes. Then converted in VB.net
I got the solution.
Following is the code.

```
Public Class Datum
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return m_name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_name = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_name As String
    Public Property unread() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_unread
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_unread = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_unread As Integer
    Public Property bookmark_order() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_bookmark_order
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_bookmark_order = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_bookmark_order As Integer
    Public Property id() As String
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_id As String
    Public Property administrator() As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
        Get
            Return m_administrator
        End Get
        Set(value As System.Nullable(Of Boolean))
            m_administrator = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_administrator As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
End Class

Public Class Paging
    Public Property [next]() As String
        Get
            Return m_next
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_next = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_next As String
End Class

Public Class Groups
    Public Property data() As List(Of Datum)
        Get
            Return m_data
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Datum))
            m_data = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_data As List(Of Datum)
    Public Property paging() As Paging
        Get
            Return m_paging
        End Get
        Set(value As Paging)
            m_paging = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_paging As Paging
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property groups() As Groups
        Get
            Return m_groups
        End Get
        Set(value As Groups)
            m_groups = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_groups As Groups
    Public Property id() As String
        Get
            Return m_id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_id = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_id As String
End Class
Dim gp As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(g.ToString)
Dim name As String = gp.groups.data(0).name.ToString
d.innertext=name
```

Anyways thanks for the help.